# Google Chrome hardware acceleration making game run slow

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

So I have been working on a game in HTML5 canvas and noticed that the games lags and performs much slower when hardware acceleration is turned on in Google Chrome then when it is turned off. You can try for yourself [here](http://claymurray.website/rts)

From doing some profiling I see that the problem lies in `drawImage`.
More specifically drawing one canvas onto another. I do a lot of this.

Hardware Acceleration on.
[image: Profile while hardware accelerated]

Hardware Acceleration off.
[image]

Is there something fundamental I am missing with one canvas to another? Why would the difference be that profound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, in-DOM canvases are loaded into GPU memory in Chrome, and off-DOM canvases may not be. So each drawImage from an off-screen canvas to an on-screen canvas results in loading the content of the canvas onto the GPU as a texture, followed by a copy of that memory on-GPU onto the on-screen canvas. The cost of sending a new texture through to the GPU can be quite high. Loading textures is high-throughput, but also high-latency, on most GPUs.

Someone from the Chrome team will have to chime in with a definitive answer, but that fits my experience with canvases in Chrome.

Comment: So appending all the canvases to the DOM could improve performance?

Comment: Possibly--it's easy to test. How big are the canvases you are copying? I've done similar things in the past, and while performance hasn't been stellar for copying canvases, it never showed up that high in the profiler for me. But I was usually copying small (under 256x256) canvases

Comment: Moving them all to DOM and layering the canvases instead of drawing them to one another did the trick.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that'll almost always be better if you have the option to do it that way. Since it was such a high percentage of your time, I assumed you were copying the same canvas on hundreds or thousands of times.

Comment: From what I figured out it was actually from scaling a really big canvas (4000x4000) into a really small canvas (200x200) for the unexplored areas.